# Redirect to previous page using Passport Facebook strategy in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, facebook, passport

Somehow, I couldn't redirect the user back after its authentication. I was using `successReturnToOrRedirect` property, but it kept sending it back to `/`. I checked `req.session.returnTo` and `req.path` and both of them have `/` as a value, even though I was calling /auth/facebook from a different page.

This was my first code:

```
 router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends']}));

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 

      passport.authenticate('facebook', { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
                                          failureRedirect: '/' })

    );
    <a href="/auth/facebook"> <div class="fb-button-login">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Continuar con <strong> facebook</strong>
        </div> </a>
```

Now I'm using a middleware that I wrote that stores req.query in req.session. It seems to work pretty fine, however I'm not sure if it's a clean solution:

```
function checkUrl (req, res, next){
  req.session.Redirect = req.query.q;
  next();
};

router.get('/auth/facebook',checkUrl, passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends']}));

router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/' }), function (req, res) {   
        res.redirect(req.session.Redirect || '/');  
    }

    );

 <a id="redirectUrl"href="/auth/facebook?q=" onClick="window.location.reload()"> <div class="fb-button-login">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Continuar con <strong> facebook</strong>
            </div> </a>

   <script> var redirectUrl = document.getElementById('redirectUrl');
                     var url = window.location.pathname;
                     redirectUrl.href = redirectUrl.href + encodeURIComponent(url);
              </script>
```